# Why do I get 'Unmatched Nets' in Altium and how do I remove them?

Tags: altium

I'm trying to import a Schematic to PCB in Altium and I get this message that there are unmatched nets cropping up:

[image: unmatched nets]

The PCB is empty, I've searched in the Schematic for them but I can't find them. Do I match them or is there a way to delete them? I don't understand why they're in the first place....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out it was sort of an artifact from earlier PCB 'experiments' on the same board when it wasn't done, went to Design -> Netlist -> Clear all Nets which solved the problem.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you for that, I've been tearing what little hair I have out over this. Have ten points!